# Angular-Laravel with Bootstrap, events are broken

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I'm trying to use in my laravel & angular project twitter bootsrap bundle but seems to be broken. On click event I get

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/modal/window.html
```

Bootstrap was included with bower

**Init Angular**

```
var konfigurator = angular.module('konfiguratorApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'konfiguratorApp.filters',
    'konfiguratorApp.services',
    'konfiguratorApp.directives',
    'konfiguratorApp.controllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngSanitize'
]
```

**Controller**

```
function Events($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
    $scope.modalEdit = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/edit',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.Off = function() {
        alert('Off');
    };
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
    };
}

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Having no big experience I try to figure out where the bootstrap templates should be present.

**Update**

Downloading the source from github works it seems to be an issue with the bower installed version